# Check that a string contains either specific special characters, alphanumeric characters and ends in alphabetical

Tags: python, regex

I want to ensure any characters in a string contain alphanumeric characters along with `_` or `,` but the string HAS to end in a alphabetical character. There also can be no whitespace anywhere.

I am trying this:

`'^[\Sa-zA-Z0-9,_][\SA-Za-z]+$'`

where I am expecting this to take care of the alphanumerics, special characters and whitepsace, `[\Sa-zA-Z0-9,_]`

and this:

`[\SA-Za-z]` to say use alphabetical characters at the very end, but that seems to fail such as:

```
import re

s = 'lk78d1'

regex = '^[\Sa-zA-Z0-9,_][\SA-Za-z]+$'

if(re.search(regex,s)):  
        print("valid")  
        
else:
     raise ValueError('non valid')
```

Comment: Just a quick tip, you can simplify `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` to `[\w]`.

Comment: I need the comma too, it is hard to see in there, nevermind it would be [\w,_] for that part

Comment: use `[\w,]` to add the comma

Comment: also remove the \S cuz it matches any non whitespace character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is that you're using `\S` which basically matches any non whitespace character i.e it overrides the remaining pattern as it includes alphanumeric characters and all symbols.

Also an improvement is to use `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. And use the ignore case flag to make it more readable.
A testable example is [at](https://repl.it/join/ayyfisqq-heraclit)

The new python code is

```
import re

s = 'lk78d1'

regex = r'^[\w,]+[a-z]$'


if(re.search(regex, s, re.IGNORECASE)):  
        print("valid")  
        
else:
     raise ValueError('non valid')
```

Comment: I am still getting non valid for this

Comment: it should be non valid as it ends with 1 which numeric not alphabetic

Comment: @StefanoPotter The regex is practically correct. If you need to only support ASCII letters/digits and one-char strings, use `regex = r'(?a)^[\w,]*[a-z]$'`. Explain what is wrong with it if it does not work as expected.